# not getting id from.xml to .java in eclipse for android

Tags: android, eclipse

I declared an id for a Button in .xml with `@+id/but1`, but from .java I can't access when pressing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> after writing:

```
Button b = (button) findViewById(R.id.
```

It's just not showing the id, if I type it manually it shows an error.

Please give a solution.

Comment: Did you save your xml file after adding the button and have Project set to Build automatically?

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is not <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, instead it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

And coming to your problem, just clean your project once. It will show the id.

Answer (score 1):

Clean the project then try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.